# Simple Math iOS?

Tags: objective-c, math, integer, equation

So in my app I am trying to do a simple math in one of my methods without using a ton of if/else statements.

So I have an integer named 'StartInt' which is at max 13. Now what I need to get is FinishInt an integer that will be the result of this pattern:

```
StartInt: 13 FinishInt: 1  
StartInt: 12 FinishInt: 2 
StartInt: 11 FinishInt: 3
```

etc... all the way down until StartInt is 1 and FinishInt is 13. Anyway how would I accomplish this? I know this must be simple but I am just not that great in Math! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All the way down until StartInt is 0 and FinishInt is 13. Anyway how
>   would I accomplish this?

That won't quite work if `startInt = 13` gives `finishInt = 1` and you want a `finishInt` to increment 1 for each decrement of `startInt`. Check out the following table:

```
13   1
12   2
11   3
10   4
 9   5
 8   6
 7   7
 6   8
 5   9
 4  10
 3  11
 2  12
 1  13
```

So you're off by 1 at either the beginning or end of your sequence. Nevertheless, it looks like you want something like this:

```
(int) calculateFinish(int startInt)
{
    int finishInt = -1;
    if (startInt >= 0 && startInt <= 13) {
        finishInt = 14 - startInt;
    }
    return finishInt;
}
```

That'd give a value of 14 for `finishInt` when `startInt = 0`.

Comment: Whoops sorry, yes when startInt is 1, the finishInt should be 13. My mistake!

Comment: @iBradApps In that case, subtracting `startInt` from 14 will give you the value you want for `finishInt`.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, for some odd reason my Math is wacky today, I thought I would need some equation for this but I guess I don't! :)

Comment: @iBradApps You do, but it's a very simple equation. ;-)

Comment: Also one quick thought or suggestion. Shouldn't finishInt be: startInt +1 - startInt? That way I just rely on the one value instead of being confused about the two? Or am I just being stupid ;)?

Comment: @iBradApps `startInt + 1 - startInt` will always give you 1. Think about that. My example was a little misleading because I assigned 13 to `startInt` -- I just meant to give some example input there. I've changed the example to a function that takes startInt as a parameter and returns the calculated `finishInt` or -1 if the input is out of range. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thats right I can't believe I didn't notice that, thanks for the help!